# Fallback to Google Assistant when My Assistant don't have any responses

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, google-assistant-sdk

We have built a custom assistant using dialog flow with limited intents. When I don't get the intent we expect, we want to fallback to default Google Assistant to take care of voice json for fulfillment. Anybody has an idea how to do it?

Comment: Are you sure this would be something that the user would expect? In conversation design recommendations, fallback intents are meant to guide the user back to the intended path.

Comment: We have two types of devices, one is with Google assistant and another is with Google Assistant installed on device, If Google assistant is installed I want to give control to it instead of handling utterances myself.